# How to automate Maven artifact deployment for both release and snapshot on CloudBees?

Tags: maven, jenkins, release, cloudbees

CloudBees gives your private Maven repositories that are integrated in the build process: [There is a check box](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/CloudBees+Private+Maven+Repository) to "deploy artifacts to my Private CloudBees Repository" as a post-build action in the project settings.

However, you have to choose between the Snapshot and the Release repository, and there is a a warning to "make sure to deploy only snapshots to the snapshot repository, and only release artifacts to the release repository".

So how do I go about setting up a project that I want continuous snapshot builds for, but also the occasional release? Do I need to set up two separate projects on CloudBees for that? Or toggle that setting manually every time there is a release? 
Do I have to take care that the pom.xml for release builds is never committed to "master" so that the Cloudbees build does not accidentally pick it up and push it to the snapshot repository?

Answer (score 3):

I think we (cloudbees) should implement this directly in deployer plugin, as it looks easy to detect archetype type (snapshot vs release) and select the adequate repository accordingly.

Have to check on actual APIs, but looks like a reasonable feature request.

Comment: Not really an answer, but +1 because I agree with the sentiment. Let me know when this is available, please. So I guess there is no good way right now, and I should use the Maven release plugin instead of this checkbox?

Comment: Anyone know if this has been implemented yet?